# Flutter Flame - SpriteSheetAnimation: How to change the row but keep frame/index

Tags: flutter, flame

I have a sprite Sheet animation where one row shows all frames of an animation. I have several rows showing the animation in different rotations. I now want to switch the rotation / change the row when the element "rotates".

Therefore I currently call

```
animation = spriteDeath.createAnimation(row: row, stepTime: 0.03);
animation!.currentIndex = index;
```

But this way, the animation just breaks thus no animation is being executed at all.
I now tried to execute

```
animation!.reset();
```

But this also doesn't change anything. How can I fix this?

What seems weird is that if during debugging I insert and remove the reset function makes the animation work all of a sudden but I cannot get it working probably from a "fresh start"

Comment: Is this within a `SpriteAnimationComponent`?

Comment: `extends SpriteAnimationComponent with HasGameRef`

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are trying to do, but I think you could use SpriteAnimationGroupComponent for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally to

```
animation!.currentIndex = index;
```

One also needs to update the clock

```
animation!.clock = clock;
```

As I have just discovered in the flutter code itself.
This means the best way to just change the rotation (as far as I now right now) is to copy the index and clock attribute from the current animation, recreate the animation for a different row and assign the clock/index again afterwards.